# How to extract contact's URL from contacts.google.com

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

The following script helps me to get the name and URL of every contact in my https://contacts.google.com.

```
function extract_contacts() {
  var s = '';
  var contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts();
    for (var i in contacts) {
      var name = contacts[i].getFullName();
      var id = contacts[i].getId();
      var url = contacts[i].getUrls();
      s+=name+" ·· "+url+"\r";
    }
  Logger.log(s);
}
```

The issue is that `getUrls` displays `UrlField` as a result, instead of the actual URL saved in that field, something like this:

```
friend ·· UrlField
another_friend ·· UrlField,UrlField
```

What should I used instead of `getUrls`?
I also need to get the Label (or Group) of every contact. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you parse through the the `URLField` array and grab the address as so:

```
function extract_contacts() {
  var s = '';
  var contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts();
    for (var i in contacts) {
      var adresses ="";
      var name = contacts[i].getFullName();
      var id = contacts[i].getId();
      var urlFields = contacts[i].getUrls();
      for (var j = 0; j < urlFields.length; j++)
        adresses += urlFields[j].getAddress() + " ";
      s+=name+" ·· "+ adresses +"\r";
    }
  Logger.log(s);
}
```

same thing for groups use `getContactGroups()` and parse through the array then use `getName()`or `getId()`.

**REFERENCES**

[URLField Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/url-field)

[contactGroup Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contact-group)

Answer (score 1):

OK. After JSmith's help and adding some replacements and alphabetical sorting, here is it. At the end, the script prints the result into a Google Sites page:

```
function extractContacts() {
  var s = '';
  var contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts();
    for (var i in contacts) {

      var adresses = "";
      var groups = "";
      var name = contacts[i].getFullName();
      var id = contacts[i].getId();

      var urlFields = contacts[i].getUrls();
      for (var j = 0; j < urlFields.length; j++)
        adresses += '* <a href="'+urlFields[j].getAddress()+'" target="_blank">'+urlFields[j].getAddress()+'</a><br>';

      var group = contacts[i].getContactGroups();
      for (var k = 0; k < group.length; k++)
        groups += group[k].getName() + " · ";

      if(adresses==''){var groups=''; var name='';}
      s+='<h3>'+groups+' · '+name+'</h3><blockquote>'+adresses+"</blockquote>#####";
    }

var s = s.replace(/System Group: My Contacts · /g,"");
var s = s.replace(/,/g,"&&&&&");

var aorder = s.split("#####").sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.localeCompare(b);
});
var s = aorder.toString();
var s = s.replace(/,/g,'<br>');
var s = s.replace(/&&&&&/g,',');
var s = s.replace(/·  ·/g,':');
var s = s.replace(/<br><h3> · <\/h3>/g,'');

var site = SitesApp.getSite('site','clicamiento');
var home = site.getChildByName('/home');
home.setHtmlContent('<h1>CLICAMIENTO</h1>'+s);

}
```